# How to store clientId and clientSecret in clientside angularjs application using OAuth2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, oauth-2.0

I am building an MEAN JS application,I want to protect my application clientId and client secret in clientside angularjs application.Where can I store these details.How to provide security for this?

For user login I have to provide these and need to get access token...new to this help me..

Comment: Don't store this sort of stuff client side.  Pretty much impossible to keep secure.  Plus, most oauth servers will only accept requests from explicitly stated domains.  Let your application server do the talking with the oauth server.  Lot's of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping client_secret at client side, you basically ruin the whole idea behind it.

So, say, Google asks client side apps to make an additional verifying call [Google OAuth docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#clientside).

If you are able to make a request from server-side, after receiving token from oauth provider pass it to server side and send token and client_secret to receive user's data.

Actually, this is much more similar to Google's [hybrid auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer), which is considered to be more secure than common oauth

Comment: Please improve a little more your answer  Starting from the link description

Comment: the link that refers to client-side apps, google says to store the client secret in JS code and adds: "(In this context, the client secret is obviously not treated as a secret.)", so that's not really an answer to the question, is it?